# What does "optic stems" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm watching an episode, some may recall which one, of a comedy show and one guy says something like this if I hear correctly:

"I looked this woman in her optic stems"

which is part of the joke, however attempting to browse around looking for the meaning did not yield any result. Is it a short form/slang of Optical System?

Can anyone shed some light on those terms?

Answer (score 4):

The "optic stems" would be the terminations of the optic nerves (which actually terminate in the retinas.)  The comedian was implying "eyes" without actually saying the word "eyes".

Comment: But the optic stems are behind the eyes. So perhaps the joke includes looking so deeply into her eyes that the person looked past her eyes, almost into her brain, to "see" what she might be thinking. Just an out-of-context guess.

Comment: I like that guess!

Answer (score 0):

When he describes how he looked her in the "optic stems" he is saying he looked her straight in the eye so he was absolutely direct and unambiguous about what he was saying.

It never happened of course. He meekly said "yes, dear."

Answer (score -1):

The Optical Stem is a system of nerves that transmit visual information from the retina of the eye to the brain.
In the 21st Century, it has been popularly put to use to imply 'eyes'.

Comment: Where has it been popularly put that way? I've never seen it used popularly (and I am exceedingly popular!).

Comment: The term 'Optical Stem' has been popularly used in the field of Ophthalmology and Iridology.